# couldn't find file 'rails-ujs' with type 'application/javascript' (On page load)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-ujs

Created a Rails 5 app using devise for auth and attempting to add Thredded gem for forums.

## Expected behavior

The app should load at http://localhost:3000.

## Actual behavior

After server starts, the following message shows up in the chrome browser where the app should be.

## couldn't find file 'rails-ujs' with type 'application/javascript'

```
System configuration

    Ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164)
    Rails 5.0.4

GemFile
    gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
    gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
    gem 'thredded', '~> 0.13.7'
    gem 'omniauth-facebook'
    gem 'geocoder'
    gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.1.1'
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'
    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think rais-ujs is included with Rails 5.1. Since you're still on 5.0 then Rails is still  dependent on jquery for UJS. Then you can just simply remove `//= require rails-ujs` from your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
gem 'rails-ujs', '~> 5.1.0.beta1'
```

Include this gem in your gem file
or use rails 5.1.4 that has it by default. Or remove it from

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
require rails-ujs #this line remove
```

Comment: Thank you.  Something so simple, sometimes we just need another pair of eyes.  Thanks again.